# Flex 4 WYSIWYG for basic HTML styling?

Tags: html, flex4, components, flash-builder

Where can I find a free WYSIWYG component that offers at least the basic HTML styling (bold, italic, underline, strikethrough)? I just need one for a simple web application with the capability to let users edit content of an HTML page. It doesn't need to be complex and all. It is only required to do minimal styling as I said on the examples above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [RichTextEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RichTextEditor.html) control should cover what you need. You can access the content (with markup) via the htmlText property.